# Hiding directory with htaccess in Wordpress homepage

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I just want to hide the `/wordpress/` in the URL of my site (`http://example.com/wordpress/`) with htaccess (I don't want to change the real URLs because I would lose all my social media shares data). I use the following htaccess in the root directory:

```
  Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
   # Turn mod_rewrite on
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
   RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+wordpress/([^\s]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule (?!^wordpress/)^(.*)$ /wordpress/$1 [L,NC]
```

It works smoothly for all the pages of my website (i.e. if I go to `example.com/wordpress/post/` it directly shows `example.com/post/`). But I have a problem with the homepage. It still always shows as `example.com/wordpress/`. I can't find the way to hide `/wordpress/` here. Can you help me?

More info:

I also have in the /wordpress/ subfolder the following default .htaccess:

```
   # BEGIN WordPress

   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /wordpress/
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L] 
    </IfModule> 
    # END WordPress
```

Comment: "I don't want to change the real urls" - actually, this is what you _should be doing_. You then just 301 redirect the "wordpress" URLs (which you are doing anyway). By doing what you've done you are effectively changing the "real URLs", but in an inefficient way. If you don't change the "real URLs" (ie. all your internal links still go to `/wordpress`) in WP then every time a user follows a link on your site they will be externally redirected, doubling the number of page requests, slowing down your users and potentially bad for SEO.

Comment: I don't understand a lot about it, but using htaccess in this way I'm keeping the Wordpress permanent and canonical links with the eatandlovemadrid.es/wordpress/post structure, even if the browser shows eatandlovemadrid.es/post. When you share it, Facebook it's still counting the shares linked to the eatandlovemadrid.es/wordpress/post url.  If I change the original Wordpress urls this won't be a good solution for me: I have a social media share counter with more than 40k interactions in some articles, and I would lose all the data and the "social reputation" of the blog.

Comment: So no one knows how to add here a rule to rewrite example.com/wordpress to example.com?

Comment: "I'm keeping the Wordpress permanent and canonical links with the eatandlovemadrid.es/wordpress/post" - well, actually you're not. By setting up a 301 redirect to the non-"wordpress" URL you are changing the canonical URL (the same as if you changed the URL in WP itself). If your "share counters" are working with your new setup, then it should(?) still work OK by doing it properly. (You could still share the "wordpress" URL. But I don't know how your "share counters" are _counting_?) As you would still need to redirect all the existing ("wordpress") URLs - which is what you are doing already.

Comment: The thing is that I already did it in the proper way but I lost all the share counts. Now with this .htaccess system even if the browser shows "eatandlovemadrid.es/post" when I enter to Wordpress I see as permalink "eatandlovemadrid.es/wordpress/post". And also when I check on Facebook debugger it shows as canonical link "eatandlovemadrid.es/wordpress/post". I don't know why, but it seems to work without changing permalinks.

In any case, do you know another method to hide the "/wordpress/" withoout changing permalinks?

Thanks a lot for your time... This is making me nuts...

Comment: "I already did it in the proper way but I lost all the share counts." - did you create redirects from the `/wordpress/` URLs to the new URL in .htaccess at this time? This is a vital step, as otherwise you would indeed lose _everything_.

Comment: Yeah, I add them, but apparently the social media shares don't follow 301 redirects... :(

Comment: I assume Facebook is getting the canonical URL from the open graph (`og:url`) tags in your page, which will include the "wordpress" directory if you've not changed the permalinks in WP itself. If this is required to maintain your "share counters" then you may well not be able to change your permalinks in WP!? There is no other way to hide "/wordpress/" (without changing WP) as you need to redirect the user (as you are doing). However, when a user looks at all the URLs on your page, they will see "/wordpress/", so it is not entirely hidden.

Answer (score 0):

> `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+wordpress/([^\s]+) [NC]`

In order to catch requests for `/wordpress/` (effectively the root of the WP site) then you would need to change the *CondPattern* in this directive to allow 0 or more trailing characters (ie. `*`). Currently, it is looking for 1 or more (ie. `+`) which excludes the bare directory. In other words:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+wordpress/([^\s]*) [NC]
```

There are presumably other "WordPress" directives in your .htaccess file that are routing the request. The order of directives are important, so there could still be a conflict.

However, as mentioned in comments, you should consider changing the URL properly in WordPress itself and then redirecting the old URL (with the "wordpress" directory) to the new URL (without "wordpress) in .htaccess. Without changing the URL structure in WP then every internal link on your site is going to result in an *external redirect*.

Comment: Thanks! But still not working at homepage: showing eatandlovemadrid.es/wordpress when I enter at eatandlovemadrid.es

Comment: You could try adding a slash prefix to the corresponding `RewriteRule` substitution. ie. Change `RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]` to `RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]` (that simply overrides the `RewriteBase` directive). Otherwise there could be a conflict with other directives. The difference between `/wordpress/` and `/wordpress/post` is that the former is a direct request for the directory, so Apache (mod_dir) internally rewrites the request to `/wordpress/index.php` (or whatever your `DirectoryIndex` states) - this needs to be overridden.

Comment: Still nothing... :( Maybe it could have anything to do with the other .htaccess that is in the Wordpress subfolder with the default content?

Comment: Ah yes, it certainly could. (The .htaccess directives above are in the document root I assume?) The .htaccess file in the "wordpress" subfolder will take priority and mod_rewrite directives are not _normally_ inherited - so it is not clear at the moment how the directives above are working at all?!

Comment: Exactly, the directives above are in the root, and inside wordpress folder is the following default code: `# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress`.

Comment: (You should add that information to your question - also helps with code formatting.)

Comment: I'm not even sure how your code is working (at all)? Is it? From what you have posted it really shouldn't be? Are there any more directives in the root .htaccess file? Do you have a `RewriteOptions` directive anywhere - in your server config?

Comment: Yeah, the root code is working well for the subpages. That's all I wrote before. THe only extra is the .htaccess inside /wordpress. But there is no more `RewriteOptions`